# Multi threaded AForge.NET training

Tags: multithreading, aforge, neural-network

I am using AForge.NET ANN and training it on my training set. Because the training is single threaded and the process can take ages, I wondered if it's possible to run a multi threaded training.

Because it is a problem to use threads while training a Resilient Backpropagation network I thought about splitting my training set between different networks and once every N epoch's, combine the weights of all networks in to one, Then, duplicate it to all threads (so the next epoch will start with the new weights).

I can't seem to find a method in the AForge.NET that combines two (or more) networks. Looking for some help on how to get started with the implementation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the neural networks every N number of iterations won't work really well.  It can be very tricky to just take the weights and combine them.  In some ways this is how the crossover operation of a Genetic Algorithm works.

Really the only way you are going to be able to do this is modify AForge's training to support multiple threads.  Basically to do this you need to map the gradient calculation and then do a reduce-sum on the gradients.  Then use the reduced gradients to update the network.

I've implemented this exact thing in the Encog Framework, it supports multi-threaded (RPROP), and has a C# version.  http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog.